# CodeIgniter UPDATE query not working with column value addition

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter Update with query builder is working fine but in my case I have to run multiple update queries in following way.

```
$query="";
foreach($result as $row)    
{
  //generate query by some procedure will look like
  //UPDATE `accounts` SET `lastbal` = lastbal + 500.00 WHERE `id` = 1;
  $balance=$row['balance];
  $accountid=$row['acid];
  //append string
  $query.= "UPDATE `accounts` SET `lastbal` = lastbal + $balance WHERE `id` = $accountid";

}
```

So $query will be like on outside of loop

```
$query=UPDATE `accounts` SET `lastbal` = lastbal + 500.00 WHERE `id` = 1;
UPDATE `accounts` SET `lastbal` = lastbal + 200.00 WHERE `id` = 2;
UPDATE `accounts` SET `lastbal` = lastbal + 60.00 WHERE `id` = 3;
```

Excution

```
$this->db->query($query);
```

I am getting errors like missing parameter blah ...blah

QUERY is running fine on **SQL console**. Is it possible to execute this query in batch mode.

I don't want to run the query inside of loop in following way

```
$this->db->set('lastbal', "lastbal+$balance", FALSE);
$this->db->where('id', $acid);
$this->db->update('accounts');
```

I want it in batch mode where column_old_value+input should available.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't want to run the query inside of loop then you have to use

Active record [$this->db->update_batch()](https://www.codeigniter.com/docs#update)

But unfortunately, in `update_batch` there is no argument option as on today to disable escape value, so

**Either**

Use this line before your query:

```
// set this to false so that _protect_identifiers skips escaping:

// Codeigniter 3.x.x
$this->db->protect_idenifiers(FALSE);

// Codeigniter 2.x.x
$this->db->_protect_identifiers=FALSE;
```

This will stop adding backticks to the built query.

and give input like below

```
$data = array();    

foreach($result as $row)    
{
    $data[] = array(
          'id' => $row['acid'] ,

          /* Give input as string */
          'lastbal'=>  'lastbal +' . $row['balance'] 
    )
}

$this->db->update_batch('accounts', $data, 'id'); 

// important to set this back to TRUE or ALL of your queries from now on will be non-escaped:
// Codeigniter 2.x.x
$this->db->_protect_identifiers=TRUE;

// Codeigniter 3.x.x
$this->db->protect_idenifiers(TRUE);
```

**Please note above will not escape your query**

**OR**

**Try this by modifying core, it will skip escaping whenever given value is array, so that rest of your query will be escaped with protect_identifiers**

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_query_builder.php#L2098

**Of function**

```
public function set_update_batch($key, $index = '', $escape = NULL)
{
..
..
..
}
```

**From**

```
'value'=>($escape === FALSE ? $v2 : $this->escape($v2))
```

**To**

```
'value'=>(is_array($v2) ? $v2[0] : ($escape === FALSE ? $v2 : $this->escape($v2)))
```

and give input like below

```
$data = array();    

foreach($result as $row)    
{
    $data[] = array(
          'id' => $row['acid'] ,

          /* Give input as array */
          'lastbal'=> array( 'lastbal +' . $row['balance'] )
    )
}

$this->db->update_batch('accounts', $data, 'id');
```

**On old CI 2.2.x**

**Modify DB_active_rec.php**

**From**

```
            if ($escape === FALSE)
            {
                $clean[$this->_protect_identifiers($k2)] = $v2;
            }
            else
            {
                $clean[$this->_protect_identifiers($k2)] = $this->escape($v2);
            }
```

**To**

```
 $clean[$this->_protect_identifiers($k2)] = (is_array($v2)? $v2[0] : ( ($escape === FALSE) ? $v2 : $this->escape($v2) ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Active record [$this->db->update_batch()](https://www.codeigniter.com/docs#update)

```
$data = array();    

foreach($result as $row)    
{
    $data[] = array(
    'id' => $row['acid'] ,
    'lastbal'=> 'accounts'.'lastbal' +  $row['balance']
    )
}

$this->db->update_batch('accounts', $data, 'id');
```